# p-dropdown clear button event is not working

Tags: angular

`<p-dropdown [showClear]="true" [filter]="true" placeholder='Location' formControlName="location" (ngModelChange)="onSearchLead()" [options]="locations" optionLabel="branchName"></p-dropdown>`

I am using p-dropdown , i need to trigger onSearchLead() when closing the selected item too.
method is triggering only when selecting the value, i need too when clearing values also

Comment: you are getting any error ?

Comment: No, method is triggering only when selecting the value, i need too when clearing  values also

Comment: use onChange method instead of ngModelChange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `onChange` event which is available in p-dropdown.

```
<p-dropdown [showClear]="true" [filter]="true" placeholder='Location' formControlName="location" (onChange)="onSearchLead()" [options]="locations" optionLabel="branchName"></p-dropdown>
```

Sample Stackblitz => https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-fsmdkb

Answer (score -1):

There is a good example for you that shows the dropdown change event :

[p-dropdown](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown)